# OData - Custom model for Create

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata

Using OData in ASP.NET Core application.

Have the resource `User` which I'm exposing as `UserDto` using `OData`.

For reading - it works fine.

For Writing, have the following endpoint.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserDto newUser) {}
```

Problem - **input parameter must be of type `UserDto`**. Which is what i'm trying to avoid (*let's say UserDto has extra fields which aren't required for creation and lacks fields which are needed*)

Possible solution

Define `Action`

```
builder.EntitySet<UserDto>("Users").EntityType
       .Action("Create").Parameter<CreateUserCommand>("command")
```

Does the above solution fits into the REST?

Is there an alternative approach to achieving the same?